# How do I convert a python string array to POINTER(c_void_p)

Tags: python, go

I'm trying to pass a python string array to Go, so I need to construct a 'GoSlice' from a python string array. A quick google search shows how to do this for integer arrays but I'm struggling to so the same for string arrays. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which package/helper are you using to bridge Python and Go?

Comment: `ctypes` Trying to create a GoSlice struct from, say , ["a", "b"] or ("a", "b") 
 ```class GoSlice(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", POINTER(c_void_p)), ("len", c_longlong), ("cap", c_longlong)]```